# Login to Xcode server stuck, "Unable to perform the request. CFNetwork error: An SSL error has occurred"

Tags: xcode, server, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup a CI workflow, so created an Xcode server on my local machine, and am trying to create a bot, but cannot get past the login to the server dialog. It simply spins and spins, but errors out.

I started off by setting up an Xcode server on my local machine.

[image]

I try to add a login to the server:

[image]

[image]

But get stuck here (login is masked in the picture):
[image]

And if I wait long enough, I get this error message:
[image]

I am using Little Snitch and a VPN, but wouldn't this be trying to connect to the local machine and not using the network?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.